# An error occurred while calling o91.sql. MERGE INTO TABLE is not supported temporarily

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I use `Glue 3.0 - Supports Spark 3.1 and Python 3` from an infrastructure perspective. I am trying to do `MERGE INTO target USING source` operation in `spark sql` for a table `UPSERT` operation. However, I am getting the below error for the same:

`An error occurred while calling o91.sql. MERGE INTO TABLE is not supported temporarily.`

I am not using any `Delta Table`, I read directly from a `postgreSQL - AuroraDb` using `spark dataframe reader` which is my `target`. The `source` here is another  `dataframe` read from `parquet file` using `spark dataframe reader`.

I have tried changing the `Glue Version` but it did not help. When I looked for answers in internet I get links to `Iceberg` and `DeltaTable`. Is my approach to the problem is correct. Please share you inputs.

The code is provided as below:

```
def changeDataCapture(inputDf, currDf, spark):
    inputDf.createOrReplaceTempView('inputDf')
    currDf.createOrReplaceTempView('currDf')
    currDf = spark.sql("""
         MERGE INTO currDf USING inputDf
            ON currDf.REG_NB = inputDf.registerNumber
           AND currDf.ANN_RTN_DT = inputDf.annual_return_date          
          WHEN MATCHED
          THEN UPDATE SET
               currDf.LAST_SEEN_DT = inputDf.LAST_SEEN_DT,
               currDf.TO_DB_DT = inputDf.TO_DB_DT,
               currDf.TO_DB_TM = inputDf.TO_DB_TM,
               currDf.BATCH_ID = inputDf.BATCH_ID,
               currDf.DATA_PROC_ID = inputDf.DATA_PROC_ID,
               currDf.FIRST_SEEN_DT = CASE
          WHEN currDf.CO_REG_DEBT = inputDf.registered_indebtedness
           AND currDf.HLDR_LIST_CD = inputDf.holder_list_indicator
           AND currDf.HLDR_LEGAL_STAT = inputDf.holder_legal_status
           AND currDf.HLDR_REFRESH_CD = inputDf.holder_refresh_flag
           AND currDf.HLDR_SUPRESS_IN = inputDf.HLDR_SUPRESS_IN
           AND currDf.BULK_LIST_ID = inputDf.Bulk_List_In
          THEN currDf.FIRST_SEEN_DT
          ELSE inputDf.FIRST_SEEN_DT
           END,
               currDf.SUPERSEDED_DT = CASE
          WHEN currDf.CO_REG_DEBT = inputDf.registered_indebtedness
           AND currDf.HLDR_LIST_CD = inputDf.holder_list_indicator
           AND currDf.HLDR_LEGAL_STAT = inputDf.holder_legal_status
           AND currDf.HLDR_REFRESH_CD = inputDf.holder_refresh_flag
           AND currDf.HLDR_SUPRESS_IN = inputDf.HLDR_SUPRESS_IN
           AND currDf.BULK_LIST_ID = inputDf.Bulk_List_In
          THEN currDf.SUPERSEDED_DT
          ELSE inputDf.SUPERSEDED_DT
           END     
          WHEN NOT MATCHED
          THEN INSERT
               (REG_NB, ANN_RTN_DT, SUPERSEDED_DT, TO_DB_DT, TO_DB_TM, FIRST_SEEN_DT, LAST_SEEN_DT, BATCH_ID,
                DATA_PROC_ID, CO_REG_DEBT, HLDR_LIST_CD, HLDR_LIST_DT, HLDR_LEGAL_STAT,
                HLDR_REFRESH_CD, HLDR_SUPRESS_IN, BULK_LIST_ID, DOC_TYPE_CD)  
          VALUES
               (registerNumber, annual_return_date, SUPERSEDED_DT, TO_DB_DT, TO_DB_TM, FIRST_SEEN_DT, LAST_SEEN_DT,
                BATCH_ID, DATA_PROC_ID, registered_indebtedness, holder_list_indicator,
                holder_list_date, holder_legal_status, holder_refresh_flag, HLDR_SUPRESS_IN, 
                Bulk_List_In, DOC_TYPE_CD)               
          """)
    return currDf
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide your code please?

Comment: Hi @RobertKossendeyt, added the code. Please have a look

Comment: Vanilla SparkSQL does not support MERGE, what are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to match 2 ```dataframes```. ```currDf``` is dataframe read from a ```PostgresDb`` and ```inputDf``` is my input. I am trying to do ```CDC``` operation. Post this operation the data would get ```UPSERT```ed into the ```postgresDb```.

Comment: SparkSQL does not support MERGE on JDBC, but only append or overwrite.

Comment: so, do I need to introduce a ```Delta Table```.  ?

Comment: Or custom logic, I still don't think I fully understand what you are trying to achieve, but vanilla Spark does not support merge.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250114/discussion-between-sds-and-robert-kossendey).

Comment: Were you able to get a solution @RobertKossendey ?

Comment: We (our dev team) decided to use Python PSYCOPG2 library to do UPSERT operation. Again its not part of PySpark